# Can I say "I cannot handle my starvation"

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, nouns

Is it proper to say this sentence below:

> I cannot handle my starvation.

I am trying to express that I am very hungry using exaggeration.

The word "starvation" represents:

> suffering or death caused by lack of food.

Which seems to be what I need here.

But I need confirmation on it. Or, do I have to say something like:

> I cannot handle how hungry I am.

Comment: Are you talking about actual starvation (being nearly dead from lack of food) or just a colloquial way of saying that you are very hungry?

Comment: @KateBunting Just a way of saying that I am very hungry, it's an exaggeration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People usually just say "I'm starving!" rather than referring to *starvation*, which sounds a bit too literal for this colloquial context.

Also, *I cannot handle* sounds rather serious. It would be more natural to say something like

> I'm so hungry I don't know what to do with myself!"

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can and it's quite correct to say that